# Unable to add Gelf config file into Azure function app

Tags: c#, azure-functions, gelf

I'm trying to setup a Gelf logger in azure function. I'm currently using this [logger](https://github.com/GokGokalp/NLog.Web.AspNetCore.Targets.Gelf) and trying to add a nlog.config file. I managed to create the file but unable to edit it, does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: Sometimes azure portal have some strange problem, you can choose to use kudu tools to edit the files.:)

Comment: Hi, any update? Can you edit now?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are develop azure function on portal, then you can edit the file directly.

If portal has some problems, you can choose to use kudu to edit the files of your function app:

1, Go to `https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

2, Then go to **D:\home\site\wwwroot>**. Then you can find the files of your function app and edit it. This can avoid facing strange problems on azure portal.

Please let me know whether this can work.

Comment: I tried with the development tools -> console. Still not work, when i try nano the file, it replied: Too many errors from stdin. In the end i gave up lol